# how to save an array of images for one parseobject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

is there a possibility to save in Parse an array of images for one object?
The image are taken from the image picker.

Im not getting through it..

Thank u!!

Comment: That's a good question, but no. You can set relations or pointers to all the pictures from one user

Comment: Thank u soulshined. How bad..

Comment: It's not that bad at all

Comment: How about we convert array to nsdata and store in Parse as object?